# Making css hover behave the same in firefox and chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

So, i'm having a bit of trouble with some css hover and tables. I got most things to work but while chrome changes the color just to the content and ignoring the padding, firefox does not. It just changes everything, padding or not. I just can't figure out how to make it look the same in both browsers even when using a css reset.

I tried this in firefox 35 and chrome 40.

Edit: Should've said that i was looking for firefox to display it like chrome does.

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/gixen/degLm3vv/) fiddle with the code.

```
span {
    height: 50px
    line-height: 50px;
    background-color: orange;
}
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
}
tr > td {
    padding-top: 6px;
}
tr:hover {
    background-color: red;    
    background-clip: content-box;
}
```

Comment: Google about `-moz-` prefix. Maybe there's one you need.

Comment: You haven't specified what your desired behaviour is. I'm going with Chrome.

Comment: background-clip works in Chrome, not FF yet , remove it and both browser will behave alike ( tr was not supposse to be seen / styled)

Answer (score 3):

In Chrome, it appears that the background-clip is being applied to the child elements, whereas in Firefox, it is being applied to the `tr` instead of the child elements.

To make Firefox behave like Chrome, simply change

```
tr:hover {
    background-color: red;    
    background-clip: content-box;
}
```

To

```
tr:hover>td {
    background-color: red;    
    background-clip: content-box;
}
```

And the background of each `td` will be clipped separately.

http://jsfiddle.net/degLm3vv/6/

The `>` operator specifies that the following CSS selector only applies to direct descendents of the previous selector. In this case direct `td` descendents of a `tr` that is being hovered over.

Answer (score -1):

if you want chrome to look like firefox you have to use the webkit- prefix

```
background-clip: webkit-content-box;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/degLm3vv/5/

Comment: Your "webkit" prefix is doing nothing because the webkit prefix is `-webkit-` not `webkit-`. Secondly, Chrome does not need a prefix for `background-clip`. If you took that line out, it would have no effect.

Comment: lol okay but do you confirm with this code its the same effect in both browsers ? for me its like that

Comment: The code has the same effect in both browsers, because it has no effect. Try taking the line out.